# Angular JS CRUD asynchronous call

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

Here is the question and the problem I have with implementing CRUD

I have one list page and I have one edit page  and each page has one controller associated with it.

Here is the code for update method which is associated with my edit page .

```
$scope.UpdateEmp = function () {

 var empl = $scope.Employee;

 empFactory.empTest.update({ EmpID: $routeParams.EmpID, empval: empl }, function (data) { // update method in my resource uses $resource

 $location.path('/EmpList'); //redirect to list

 });

 };
```

**Problem 1:**

Here I have included the redirect operation ($location) in my success call. Ideally on completion of the update, redirection has to take place but due to the concept of promise object return, its getting redirected even before the update(My understanding from promise)

Here on success, I m redirecting to the List page where I m assigning the model. This part of the code associated with list page. My understanding is that, it will get executed everytime when the list page loads. (From the debugging , I could see its happening as well but not making call to API GET method on every refresh)

```
 $scope.Employees= empFactories.query();
```

**Problem 2:**

Query makes call to the API controller get method for fetching the data. The call to API controller not happening every time when I refresh the page. Its happening randomly. I tried to include cache: false in my $resource call to the API method but it doesn't cause call to API GET method everytime as well.

**Update 1:**

With network play button "on" in the Internet Explorer F12 option, I could see the update operation working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to my problem

In the above example, I m making use of MVC controller. I should have called it out explicitly. Hence call to the Get method is not happening everytime, when I added the attribute as below, it started working fine

```
 [OutputCache(NoStore=true,Duration=0,VaryByParam="None")]
```

I tried the same example with WebAPI controller, in that case, without the attribute its worked perfectly

Trying out things in a different way took lot of time and helped to learn new stuff:)